# Join on a selected column

Tags: mysql

My query basically looks like this:

```
SELECT a,   
    (SELECT name
     FROM table3 
     LIMIT 1) as b
FROM table1
GROUP BY b
```

However, I get an error saying "Unknown column 'b' in group statement".

So, how do I correctly assign an alias to this subselected column?

edit: What I am actually trying to do is a little more complicated. I have products assigned to subcategories. One product may have multiple subcategories. Every subcategory is assigned to a main category, and one product may only have subcategories that are all in one main category. Then I have a column with spendings that assigns prices to products. Now when I want to see how much money was spent in a certain main category I join tables and group them by main category and use SUM( price ). However, if one product has multiple subcategories, it is counted several times. The query here is the only way I have found so far that omits this issue.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Currently this seems to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: You don't need to alias the subselected column, just use `GROUP BY name` instead of `GROUP BY b`. Even then your overall query would be incorrect because your GROUP BY list and SELECT list would be different.

Comment: The answer below solved my problem. Thank you very much for your effort, Aziz!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT a,   
  (SELECT name
   FROM table3 
   LIMIT 1) as b
  FROM table1
) as R
GROUP BY b
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Select in Select Statement

Like this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT a,(SELECT name FROM table3 LIMIT 1) as b FROM table1
) As Temp

GROUP BY b
```